# Would using a single pass of schred on an encrypted SSD be an effective way to prevent accessing file data?

Tags: ssd, security, filesystems, encryption, wipe

If I would perform a single pass of `schred` on a file on a (self)-**encrypted** SSD, would there still be a way to retrieve the file data without knowing the encryption key / password? Assume that the attacker may be able to take over the computer that controls the SSD.

The well know problem with an SSD is that it copies data all over the flash even during normal writes to a file. However, on an encrypted drive I presume there is no way to extract that data directly from flash. Is this correct?

If so, I would suppose the only way to get to the data is through local access to the system that contains the SSD. In that case a single `schred` should destroy the data that is accessible within the logical sectors on the disk, right?

I presume hacking the controller chip could still be an issue (?) Are there any other possible attacks that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you talking about a self-encrypting SSD or a user-level encryption like Bitlocker, VeraCrypt?

Comment: Mainly self-encrypting, maybe I'll need another answer for the user-level encryption (although I don't think it changes all that much).

Comment: I not 100% sure but I would expect that the "master encryption key" that is used by the SSD is just stored in flash. Therefore unless you do a secure erase it should be possible to read out the deleted data and the encryption key on flash level. Of course on SATA/NVMe level you should not be able to extract the key

Comment: @Robert Good point. I guess that would depend on the implementation, but maybe it is too much to expect that the controllers (usually specialized ARM chips if I'm not mistaken) contain a secure element in them. On the other hand, they must already have an AES accelerator in there otherwise you'll never get enough throughput. Still I would not be overly surprised if I found a key in flash that encrypted by the firmware or something similar. Possibly they use a combition of a firmware key and the passphrase. I honestly don't know.

Comment: OH, there is a spec, OPAL 2.0. Yeah, the encryption key is encrypted by the passphrase if it is set. So that's alright if and only if the passphrase is secure enough. Let's assume that it is for this question.

Comment: I had a stand-alone self-encrypting drive in mind without external "software solution" attached. But independently of that `shred` does not "destroy the data" instead it just makes them unavailable as the used sectors just get "unassigned" (not assigned to an actual sector address). Hence the data is still there but can not be read. You should get the same result by deleting the file + execute TRIM.

Comment: @Robert That may be the case, but I found out that it is entirely unclear when TRIM is executed. Deleting files is commonly just dereferencing them in the FS as far as I know. So I'm not sure if the data in the sectors is still available as long as TRIM is not executed. That's why I thought that shredding the data logically would at least make the data unavailable at the FS level, which just operates at sectors level as far as I know (although that may be too simplistic from my side)...